# Linux installation as root

Tags: linux, selenium, npm

I created a user in a linux box. Under that user, I want to install selenium webdriver using npm.(I have npm installed)

```
  npm install selenium-webdriver
```

In normal situations, when I install after unzipping a tar ball, I make file under the user name but install as root.
I was told to do this way, I am curious why I do that as root. Here is my question.

1. Why do I need to install as root? I know this is because the user is not allowed to install but I want to know more in detail in terms of file structure.
2. Do I need to install selenium webdriver as root too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why do I need to install as root? I know this is because the user is not allowed to install but I want to know more in detail in terms of file structure.

It's not so much that the user is not allowed to *install*. There's no such thing as an *install* operation as far as the Linux OS is concerned. There are installation commands but the OS never gets a request from these commands about *installing* anything. What it sees are filesystem operations like reading and writing files. For instance, if I install a `foo` package that provides a `foo` command, installing it with `make install` will (most likely) try to write to `/usr/local/bin/foo` but very often only `root` is able to write files there. So you have to be `root` to write there.

> 2. Do I need to install selenium webdriver as root too?

While there are probably cases where installing it as `root` makes sense, you generally do not need to be `root` to install it. I typically use the Python version of Selenium. However, I sometimes answer questions on SO about `selenium-webdriver` but I do not keep it installed. So whenever I need to use it to answer a question, I create a temporary directory to write the code that will go in my answer and run `npm install selenium-webdriver` there so that I have a local copy installed in `node_modules`. No need to be `root`.

Comment: Thank you. so which directory do you recommend to install webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Root itself is a user, who have all the privileges or default access to all commands and files on the linux OS.
Root permission are required for installation of packages or softwares because of the need to write to system directories.

Many tasks require root privileges include moving files/directories into or out of system directories.
As directories that are critical to the functioning of the operating system.